# wrong calculation when using float

Tags: c, variables, math, double, calculation

I'm trying to do a calculation and for some reason when I'm using float I'm getting -nan(ind) but when I'm changing the variables (x,y) to double I'm getting to right answer maybe you guys have any idea why its happening ?
Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define pi 3.1416
#define L1 0.5
#define L2 0.5

void main()
{
    float q1[12], q2[12], q1_Degrees[12], q2_Degrees[12];
    float x = 0.8;
    float y = 0.6;

    q2[0] = acos((pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2) - pow(L1, 2) - pow(L2, 2)) / (2 * L1*L2));
    q1[0] = atan(y / x) - atan((L2*sin(q2[0])) / (L1 + L2 * cos(q2[0])));

    q1_Degrees[0] = (q1[0] * 180) / pi;
    q2_Degrees[0] = (q2[0] * 180) / pi;

    printf_s("q1 is = %.1f q2 is = %.1f\n\n", q1_Degrees[0], q2_Degrees[0]);
}
```

[image]

Comment: You're using `%.1f` with `double`??

Comment: All flavors of `%f` are valid for float or double.

Answer (score 4):

2 concerns

**acos()**

The `x` in `acos(x)` needs to be in the range `[-1...1]`.  Outside that, the result may be NaN.

`(pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2) - pow(L1, 2) - pow(L2, 2)) / (2 * L1*L2)` is prone to slight effects of computation that result in a value just outside [-1...1] even if mathematically the result should be in range.

A quick work-around:

```
double z = (pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2) - pow(L1, 2) - pow(L2, 2)) / (2 * L1*L2);
if (z < -1.0) z = -1.0;
else if (z > 1.0) z = 1.0;
q2[0] = acos(z);
```

The issue applies to `double`, `float`, `long double`.  The fact it "worked" with one type is no reason to believe code is robust with other values.

Note that code is calling `double` functions like `acos(), pow()` and not their `float` counterparts `acosf(), powf()`.  I recommend to use `double` throughout unless you have a compelling reason otherwise.

**atan**

`atan()` provides a [-π/2... +π/2] radians (aka [-90...90] degrees) result.

A whole circle result of [-π... +π] radians (aka [-180...180] degrees) is available with `atan2(y,x)`

```
atan((L2*sin(q2[0])) / (L1 + L2 * cos(q2[0])))
// or 
atan2(L2*sin(q2[0]), L1 + L2 * cos(q2[0]))
```

---

A better solution is to use a different form of trig manipulation that does not depend on the edge of `acos()`.  Easiest to do if OP also posted the higher level goal of the exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting accumulated roundoff which runs a bit past the domain of `acos()`.

Simplifying your example to a minimum that shows the issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define L1 0.5
#define L2 0.5

int main()
{
    float x = 0.8;
    float y = 0.6;

    float acos_param = (pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2) - pow(L1, 2) - pow(L2, 2)) / (2 * L1*L2);
    float q2 = acos(acos_param);

    printf("acos_param = %.9f; q2 = %.9f\n", acos_param, q2);

    return 0;
}
```

And running this - with floats - we see:

```
acos_param = 1.000000119; q2 = nan
```

Aha: greater than 1.0 is out of range of `acos` so you get `NaN` (not a number).

Changing all the `float` to `double` we get:

```
acos_param = 1.000000000; q2 = 0.000000000
```

which is more in line with expectations.

**EDIT** - Expanding on comments in the comments, variadic functions in C *always* pass floating-point values as `double`, and the misleadingly-named format `%f` really means `double`, not `float`.

Even if you attempt to cast "down" to a `float`, it will get promoted again back to double before it's called, but will truncate the precision.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double d1 = 0.8;
    double d2 = (float)0.8;

    printf("d1=%.9f; d2=%.9f\n", d1, d2);

    return 0;
}
```

Which on my compiler produces:

```
d1=0.800000000; d2=0.800000012
```

Here, `d1` is the full real-deal double, while `d2` is the float-truncated version promoted back to double.

And in no case is the `l` format specifier need; `%f` and `%lf` are the same thing.

Comment: Same problem may happen with `double x,y`.  Printing to 9 places may not readily show it.  20 would be better.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica on my compiler, changing all float to double works properly, but it seems clear this bit of math is dancing at the edge of available precision and depends too much on which way the wind blows.

Answer (score 1):

Some basic debugging:

First, you can narrow down your code to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void main()
{
    float x = 0.8;
    float y = 0.6;
    double q = acos((pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2) - 0.5) * 2);
    printf("q = %lf\n", q);
}
```

Then, it becomes obvious that either `pow(x, 2)` or `pow(y, 2)` yield slightly different results for `float` and `double`.

At this point, let's investigate the actual differences:

1. Between the value of `(float)0.8` and the value of `(double)0.8`
2. Between the value of `(float)0.6` and the value of `(double)0.6`

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    printf("(float)0.8 = %.10f\n", (float)0.8);
    printf("(double)0.8 = %.10lf\n", (double)0.8);
    printf("(float)0.6 = %.10f\n", (float)0.6);
    printf("(double)0.6 = %.10lf\n", (double)0.6);
}
```

The printout is:

```
(float)0.8 = 0.8000000119                                                                                             
(double)0.8 = 0.8000000000                                                                                            
(float)0.6 = 0.6000000238                                                                                             
(double)0.6 = 0.6000000000
```

Does that answer your question?

Comment: A *variadic* function like `printf` automatically promotes all floats to double, so you don't have to ask the compiler to do it for you.

Comment: @SteveFriedl: Thank you, but how exactly is that related to the answer?

Comment: Since they're all doubles, `%f` and `%lf` are the same thing (the `l` is ignored).  [unless the standard has changed in the last decade or so]

Comment: @SteveFriedl: So you're saying that `(float)0.8` and `(double)0.8` are the exact same value, but `printf` output is somehow misleading?

Comment: It's not printf that's misleading, it's the casts. ALL those are passed as `double`, but the one with the `(float)` cast throws away the higher precision before passing it as a double which is memorialized the low-precision value in a high-precision variable.

Comment: @SteveFriedl: So you're saying I could have gotten rid of the `l` in `lf`... Great, but like I initially asked - how exactly is that related to the answer? I mean - to the actual answer, not to the fact that I was "too explicit" about the types (BTW, I doubt that there is anything bad about being too explicit when it comes to type casting). My point was to show this dude how to conclude where the difference stems from, and what exactly (or roughly) that difference is. Not to teach him (or her) about `printf` implicit type conversions which he (or she) can rely on.

Comment: My reading of your answer suggested some confusion about how float/double promotions work in `printf`; if my expanded answer is all old news to you, then I'm sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: @SteveFriedl: Not at all, I just said that the main focus of the answer was to illustrate the actual differences between `float` and `double` in this specific context. You basically told me something like, hey - the compiler knows it's double, you don't need to tell him that.

Comment: The casts in the code snippet are good and illustrative although I recommend `%.20f` (just one `f` for all) to show that the `double 0.6` is not not exactly 0.6 either.

Comment: On a pedantic note: `printf("%.30f %.30f\n", (double)0.6, 0.6);` _may_ print differently when `FLT_EVAL_METHOD == 2`.  Have to think about that.  Maybe a good SO question.  Hmmm.